# wacom tablet crashes on first stylus click

Tags: crash, tablet, wacom

Using my Wacom Intuos M Pistachio tablet on Ubuntu 20.04.1 via USB cable it consistently crashes the first time the stylus touches the pad.  The pointer moves around fine until the stylus touches the pad then it crashes.

I run sudo rmmod wacom ; sudo modprobe wacom  and then it usually logs me out (looks like the desktop restarts) and then comes back in works fine.  Sometimes it reboots.

I've seen similar reports elsewhere but no reasonable fix.  e.g.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3163

and

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/touching-wacom-tablet-crashes-linux-4175571470/

The second link references a kernel patch which is beyond me!

Anyone able to help?  I've got the following in apport.log

`ERROR: apport (pid 106735) Mon Nov  9 16:59:41 2020: called for pid 1216, signal 6, core limit 0, dump mode 2
ERROR: apport (pid 106735) Mon Nov  9 16:59:41 2020: not creating core for pid with dump mode of 2
ERROR: apport (pid 106735) Mon Nov  9 16:59:41 2020: executable: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (command line "/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -display
fd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3")
ERROR: apport (pid 106735) Mon Nov  9 16:59:41 2020: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 106735) Mon Nov  9 16:59:45 2020: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash`

And a huge crash log in /var/crash ...

Any help appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this exact model (Wacom 6100WL) on Ubuntu 20.04. When connected via usb tablet freezes the moment you touch the pad with stylus. Sometimes it resulted in desktop reboot.

Looking for solution I've done several things like installing `input-wacom` driver from source:

- https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source

or resetting X Driver configuration:

- https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Tablet-Configuration-3%3A-GNOME-3#remove-existing-configuration

However, in my case while moving the stylus I also noticed that my tablet incorrectly maps the screen. Additionally, the `xsetwacom --list devices` command was returning only two positions, when connected via USB:

```
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos BT M stylus   id: 20  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos BT M eraser   id: 21  type: ERASER
```

I found solution to this problem described here:

- https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Known-Issues#android-misdetect

It seems this Wacom model is affected by some detection issue that puts the tablet into "Android mode" when connecting it to Ubuntu system. So if the status led on your tablet is dimmed you have to hold two outermost buttons on the tablet for approximately 4 sec to switch it back to "PC mode". The led will brighten up and the device should work fine after that. Unfortunately, you have to repeat this procedure every time you connect your device.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I still have the issue and none of the fixes in that link seem to work (e.g. holding down the buttons etc.)  Anyway, you've pointed me towards the relevant github so I've raised a new issue with these details... thanks!